# Change IP addresses to regex

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, notepad++

Is there a way to use regular expression search and replace function in notepad++ to change ip addresses to a range for below?

With below

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.96.0.0/14
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.0.0/17
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.128.0/22
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.160.0/19
```

To be changed to something like

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.96.0.([0-1][0-4])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.0.([0-1][0-7])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.128.([0-2][0-2])$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^14.102.160.([0-1][0-9])$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by searching for

```
0/(\d)(\d)
```

and replacing all with

```
\([0-\1][0-\2]\)$
```

but are you sure you're doing the right thing?

`([0-2][0-2])` doesn't match the range from `00` to `22`, it matches `00`, `01`, `02`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `20`, `21` and `22` (and nothing else)...

Comment: +1, but you need to escape the round brackets in the replacement string (tested, no idea why.)

Comment: Thanks for this so how do you have ranges from 0-22 for example?

Comment: @Jae: That would be `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-2])`. Which makes it impossible to achieve a general solution for your problem using regex alone.

Comment: I just wanted ip ranges with this kind regex that covers those ranges for each country that I wanted to redirect. Is there some source where I can obtain this? It seems too hard to achieve this

Comment: @Jae: You'll need a programmatic solution. I don't know if you can script Notepad++ - what programming languages do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @stema round brackets in a Notepad regex replacement invoke processing options. For example the string "(?1found:absent)" will insert "found" if the sub-expression that $1 would insert was matched and with "absent" otherwise. So useful with regex searches such as "(abc)|(def)" to which part matched. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html